# RLock(s) were not greened, Eventlet.monkey(patch) error

Tags: networking, mininet, sdn, topology, ryu

I am trying to run a topology discovery script on mininet for the purpose of my thesis, but i am repeatedly getting this eventlet error even after trying it out in different ways. Below is the code: Could anyone please help me out to fix it? This is the error i am getting

" RLock(s) were not greened, to fix this error make sure you run eventlet.monkey_patch() before importing any other modules."

import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()

I added these two lines as stated by chatgpt as this adds necessary modules in the eventlet library before any other modules are imported. I expected this to resolve the issue but i am still facing the same error.

Comment: I have the same issue but I'm running a celery task manager on Windows.